# Nested .xpath('@attribute') gives an empty result if some tags don't have the attribute

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am scraping a site using scrapy. There is a list of div some are display none and other are display block. I only want to fetch data from the div that are display block.
But i am not able to fetch the style attribute from the div. I also checked a solution on stackoverflow ie

```
response.xpath("//div").xpath("@style").extract()
```

this gives me a blank list in output.
It is not fetching the style attribute.
Or can I get the raw HTML using scrapy then with the help of beautiful soup get the style attribute from the div?
or is if i can get the raw html in string that will be also helpful. all i want is style aatribute in it.

**Sample html :-**

```
<div class="asd">div content need to extract</div>

<div class="asd" style="display:none">no need to extract</div>
```

Comment: There's no `style` attribute in the tag you pointed to. Do you want to extract the inherited style?

Comment: as you can see there is a style attribute in one div only and it is none. So I want to scrap the data from the div that don't have the style attribute display:none.

Comment: But when i am fetching div with scrapy then i am getting data from both divs.

Answer (score 0):

based on your sample html this solution might be useful(using beautifulsoup):

```
divs = soup.select('div.asd')
theDiv = [div for div in divs if 'style' not in div.attrs]
```

Comment: you are doing this with beautiful soup. But i am fetching the html with scrapy.

Comment: i am thinking to use selenium with beautiful soup but in that case i have to rewrite code. and that will be time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me your `xpath` is off, try this one:

```
response.xpath("//div/@style").extract()
```

or:

```
response.xpath("//div").xpath("./@style").extract()
# notice the relevant path here^^
```